# error al crear un Actualizar una tabla con mysql(heidi)

Tags: mysql

intento hacer un update de una tabla enlazas mutuamente que seriam DocumentosEnviados y DocumentosEnvia2 las 2 tablas contiene mismos campos todos los campos son varchar 
el error es [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
este es mi query

```
update a set a.codigo_estado=b.codigo_estado,a.detalle_estado=b.detalle_estado
 from DocumentosEnviados a inner join DocumentosEnvia2 b on a.nrodoc=b.nrodoc and a.serdoc=b.serdoc
 where a.codigo_estado<>b.codigo_estado and b.codigo_estado='2' ;
```

al intentar hacer un select normal me bota lo que quiero actualizar 
query
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
    select *  from DocumentosEnviados a inner join DocumentosEnvia2 b on a.nrodoc=b.nrodoc and a.serdoc=b.serdoc
     where a.codigo_estado<>b.codigo_estado and b.codigo_estado='2' ;

TABLAs que uso tiene mismos campos

```
create table sysmacon_fi.DocumentosEnvia2
(
id int primary key auto_increment, pdoano varchar(4),coddro varchar(10),fyhcre datetime, TipoDoc varchar(500),serdoc varchar(500),nrodoc varchar(500),codaux varchar(500), campo4 varchar(500) ,campo5 varchar(500) ,campo6 varchar(500),campo7 varchar(500),campo8 varchar(500)
,campo10  varchar(500), 
campo11  varchar(500),campo12  varchar(500),campo13  varchar(500),campo14 varchar(500) ,campo15 varchar(500) ,campo16 varchar(500) ,
campo17  varchar(500),campo18  varchar(500),campo19  varchar(500),campo20 varchar(500),campo21 varchar(500) ,campo22 varchar(500) ,
campo24  varchar(500),campo25  varchar(500),campo26 varchar(500) ,campo27 varchar(500) ,campo28 varchar(500) ,campo29 varchar(500),
campo30  varchar(500),campo31  varchar(500),campo32 varchar(500) ,campo33 varchar(500) ,campo34 varchar(500) ,campo35  varchar(500),
campo37 varchar(500) ,campo38  varchar(500),campo39 varchar(500) ,campo40 varchar(500) ,campo41 varchar(500) ,campo42  varchar(500),
campo43  varchar(500),campo44  varchar(500),campo45 varchar(500) ,campo46 varchar(500) ,campo47 varchar(500),campo48 varchar(500)
,campo49 varchar(500),campo50 varchar(500)
 ,campo51 varchar(500) ,campo52 varchar(500),campo53 varchar(500) ,campo54  varchar(500),
campo55  varchar(500),campo56  varchar(500),campo57 varchar(500) ,campo58 varchar(500),campo59 varchar(500),campo61 varchar(500),campo62 varchar(500),
campo64 varchar(500) ,campo65  varchar(500),
campo66  varchar(500),campo67  varchar(500),campo68 varchar(500) ,campo69 varchar(500) ,campo70 varchar(500) ,campo71 varchar(500) ,
campo72  varchar(500),campo73  varchar(500),campo74 varchar(500),campo75  varchar(500),campo76  varchar(500),campo77  varchar(500),
campo78  varchar(500),campo79  varchar(500),campo81 varchar(500),campo83 varchar(500),campo84 varchar(500),campo85 varchar(500),codigo_estado varchar(2),
Detalle_estado varchar(500) ,visto varchar(10)
);
```

Comment: El problema es que no puedes hacer un UPDATE con la sentencia FROM. Lo que necesitas es hacer una consulta anidada que dentro del UPDATE tenga toda una sentencia SELECT con su FROM.

Comment: gracias por tu comentario me diste una idea pude solucionarlo añado solucion

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE DocumentosEnviados t1
INNER JOIN DocumentosEnvia2 t2 ON t1.nrodoc = t2.nrodoc and t1.serdoc=t2.serdoc 
SET t1.codigo_estado = t2.codigo_estado,t1.detalle_estado=t2.detalle_Estado
where t1.codigo_estado<>t2.codigo_estado and t1.codigo_estado='2' ;
```

Comment: Esta es una respuesta?

Comment: si, me soluciono el inconveniente

Comment: Entonces explícalo, pues solo poner código se considera de baja calidad

Comment: @DannyloRamos como te indica otro usuario, las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad porque no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios que se encuentren en un problema similar. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para indicar qué cambiaste y/o por qué cambiarlo solucionó el problema. Saludos.

Comment: Adicionalmente te recomiendo leer el artículo [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)